# SFDX force:source:retrieve won't pulldown Workflow, WorkflowFieldUpdate, WorkflowRule, WorkflowAlert

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, mdapi, source

I have tried the following:

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Workflow, WorkflowAlert, WorkflowFieldUpdate,  WorkflowRule, ApprovalProcess, CustomObject:FF__Process__c"`

Trying to get a specific update didn't work either:

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m  "WorkflowFieldUpdate:FF__Process__c.Update_Last_Approval_Action_Field  CustomObject:FF__Process__c"`

** my sfdx cli version: `sfdx-cli/7.90.2-b8f9206a5c darwin-x64 node-v14.15.4`
** I don't know if it matters but my custom object is from an installed package.

**However,** when I retrieve using metadata api format along with package.xml I am successfully able to get all these things, they are all neatly retrieved in the worflow folder under the object name.

I use this command and a sample of the package:

`sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -k manifest/package.xml -r .`

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Workflow</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>FF__Process__c.BIA_BIA_Approved</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.BIA_BIA_Rejected</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.BIA_BIA_Submitted_for_Approval</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.BIA_Submitted_for_Approval_Initial_Action</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Alternate_Operational_Resiliency_Lead</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Alternate_Resiliency_Lead</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Business_Manager</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Key_SME</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Operational_Resiliency_Lead_1</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Operational_Resiliency_Lead_2</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Operational_Resiliency_Lead_3</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Admin_1</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Admin_10</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Admin_2</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Admin_3</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Admin_4</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Admin_5</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Admin_6</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Admin_7</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Admin_8</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Admin_9</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Coordinator_1</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Coordinator_2</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Coordinator_3</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Lead</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Lead_2</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.New_Role_Assigned_BIA_Resiliency_Lead_3</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Role_Attrition_Resiliency_Admin_BIA</members>
    <name>WorkflowAlert</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Approval_Status_to_Approved</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Approval_Status_to_Rejected</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Approval_Status_to_Submitted</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Approved_By</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Approved_Date_Time</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Rejected_By</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Rejected_Date_Time</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Submitted_By</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Submitted_Date_Time</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Uncheck_Launch_GWF</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Uncheck_Submit</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Uncheck_Submit2</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Update_GWF_Reset</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Update_Last_Approval_Action_Field</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Update_Last_Approval_Action_Field_Approv</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Update_Last_Approval_Action_Field_Reject</members>
    <members>FF__Process__c.Update_Launch_GWF</members>
    <name>WorkflowFieldUpdate</name>
</types>
<types>
    <name>WorkflowRule</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Have you this command: sfdx force:source:retrieve --metadata WorkflowRule:WorkflowruleName.

Comment: yes, tried that - but didn't work. WARNING: The following metadata isn’t in your org. If it’s not new, someone deleted it from the org.
Entity of type 'WorkflowRule' named XXXXXXX cannot be found